# ¿Cómo ver las diferencias de un archivo con un commit específico?

Tags: git, git-commit

¿Cómo puedo ver la diferencia entre el archivo tal y como está ahora (sin haber hecho commit) y un commit específico del pasado?

Conozco la sintaxis para comparar dos commits:

```
git diff <commit1> <commit2> fichero
```

Pero en este caso no hay commit2, pues está "not staged for commit":

```
$ git status
On branch feature-probando_git
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/feature-probando_git'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   config.py
```

El log de cambios es como sigue:

```
$ git log
commit ZZZ
Author: yo
Date:   Wed Dec 21 11:12:13 2016 +0100

    Hola hola hola.

commit YYY
Author: yo
Date:   Wed Dec 21 10:11:12 2016 +0100

    Adiós adiós adiós.

commit XXX
Merge: aaa bbb
Author: yo
Date:   Mon Dec 19 09:10:11 2016 +0100

    Este commit es el bueno.
```

Por lo que querría ver la diferencia entre `config.py` actual y su contenido tras el commit `XXX`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

¡Lo encontré!

Igual que tenemos `git diff commitXXX commitZZZ config.py` para comparar el archivo `config.py` entre el commit `commitXXX` y `commitZZZ`, también podemos comparar con el commit `XXX` diciendo simplemente:

```
git diff commitXXX config.py
```

Si queremos comparar tooodos los archivos, simplemente debemos eliminar la referencia a archivos de nuestro comando:

```
git diff commitXXX
```

El resultado es del tipo:

```
$ git diff commitXXX config.py
diff --git a/config.py b/config.py
index sss..ttt 100644
--- a/config.py
+++ b/config.py
@@ -123,7 +123,7 @@ configurations = {
             },
             'hola': {}
         },
-        'valores': {
+        'valor': {
             'cliente': {
                 'nombre': '...',
                 'ip': '...',
```